# Clever way to prove $\langle A,X\rangle=x^TAx$ with $X=xx^T$, $A\in S^n$?

Tags: matrices, trace, adjoint-operators

How to prove $\langle A,X\rangle=x^TAx$ with $X=xx^T$, $A\in S^n$?  (inner product of matrices)

1. $xx^T$ is rank one.

The following is one way to prove it:

$$\langle A,X\rangle=\text {tr}(AX)$$

Therefore,  listing the trace of $AX$ and compare it to $x^TAx$ is one way.

---

Is there any other clever way to prove it?

The following is what I am thinking:
 $\langle A,X\rangle = \langle A,xx^T \rangle$
and
$\langle x,Ax\rangle =x^TA^Tx=x^TAx$

Therefore, can I say that
$\langle A,xx^T \rangle=\langle Ax,x^T \rangle $  ? and why?
(It is something related to adjoint?)

Comment: What's $\langle A,X\rangle$ in this context?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you have in mind: If you are defining $\langle A , X \rangle := \operatorname{tr}(AX)$, then there's no way of getting around using the properties of trace here.

Comment: @Travis That is the definition of inner product of matrices.  And I am trying to prove it by using adjoint concept. I do not know if it can work.

Comment: @sleevechen Well, it's *one* inner product on the space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$, so $\text{tr}(Axx^T) = \text{tr}((Ax)x^T) = \text{tr}(x^TAx) = x^TAx$.

Comment: Ok, I know where the key point is.

Comment: Brilliant. Thx!